# Как правильно оформлять try / catch в коде?

Tags: c#, исключения, форматирование

Начал очень часто сталкиваться с конструкциями **try / catch**, обычно оформляю их так:

```
try
{
     //Много кода
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Много кода
}
```

Теперь, скажем у меня что-то вроде:

```
try
{
     double.Parse("a"); //Тут только одна строчка
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
     //Ничего не делать
}
```

Будет ли плохо, если я напишу это так:

```
try
    { double.Parse("a"); }
catch (ArgumentException e) { }
```

Или так:

```
try { double.Parse("a"); }
catch (ArgumentException e) { }
```

Ну или например, вместо:

```
try
{
    return Convert.ToDouble(input);
}
catch (Exception e)
{ 
    return default(int);
}
```

Написать:

```
try
    { return Convert.ToDouble(input); }
catch
    { return default(int); }
```

Просто заметил, что очень часто **try / catch** проверяющий одну - две строки занимает по факту целых 8 - 9 и захотелось узнать, как можно в таких случаях поступить?

Comment: то, о чем вы спрашиваете, называется code conventions. Зависит исключительно от предпочтений вашей команды и/или ваших. С точки зрения языка важен только синтаксис. Лишние строки - вопрос спорный, кому-то мешают, кому-то наоборот. Нет тут универсального "правильного" решения.

Comment: @rdorn Я знаю что на python есть PEP - там все правила оформления кода. Неужели нет аналогов для C#?

Comment: если интерестно, есть доки мелкософта по этому поводу - [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions)

Comment: Но, должен сказать, что всетаки rdorn полностью прав и компании/команды не редко составляют свои `code conventions` которым и прийдется следовать

Comment: понятия не имею что такое PEP, но как ставить фигурные скобочки и какую нотацию использовать для имен переменных, методов, писать ли this при обращении к членам класса, пробелы или табы и т.д. периодически вызывает споры даже внутри команд =), так что считайте что аналога нет. Все что позволяет синтаксис языка вы можете использовать так, как договоритесь внутри команды.

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych В доках про оформление самого try / catch ничего нет, только сказано, что им рекомендуется ловить исключения...

Comment: @rdorn Ясно, ну что ж, спасибо!)

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych у microsoft в коде тоже бардак с соглашениями =) посмотрите хотя бы исходники BCL на refferencesource

Comment: @Андрей Конечно знаю про TryParse, это просто для примера. А насчёт указания переменной - спасибо, не знал!

Comment: @Андрей не говорите чуши. Создание StackTrace не зависит от указания имени для переменной.

Comment: @Philippe - смотрите [Framework Design Guidelines](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/) - это выдержка из одноимённой книги (считается must read для дотнетчиков). На русском - [Рекомендации по проектированию Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229042(v=vs.110).aspx). Книга в переводе на русский называется "Инфраструктура программных проектов".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, обработка ошибок — это очень сложная часть программирования. Да, она часто требует большого объёма кода, и это нормально. Вы не должны пытаться уменьшить объём кода, ухудшая качество кода и экономя на обработке ошибок. Целью написания кода является правильный код, а не маленький код по объёму.

По поводу оформления кода отступами/переносами строк, придерживайтесь стиля, принятого в вашей команде. Никаких рекомендаций по этому поводу нет. Я бы не экономил строчки путём втискивания кода в одну строку, но это вопрос личных предпочтений.

А вот от игнорирования ошибок я бы вас предостерёг. Код наподобие

```
try
{
     double.Parse("a"); //Тут только одна строчка
}
catch (ArgumentException e)
{
     //Ничего не делать
}
```

который просто проглатывает ошибку, скорее всего написан плохо: вместо того, чтобы выявить ошибку в другой части программы, мы просто закрываем на неё глаза, не думая о том, как же будет вести себя программа в исключительном случае.

(Ну и в случае, когда исключение имеет хорошие шансы возникнуть и ошибки стоит ожидать, предпочтительно пользоваться функциями наподобие `TryParse`. Оставьте исключения для исключительных ситуаций.)

Answer (score 1):

В любой подобной ситуации с вопросом форматирования:

1. В главную очередь смотрим стандарты, принятые в команде разработчиков вашего проекта.
2. Если там не решения нашли — обращаемся к Сode conventions.

P.S. Мартин Роберт советует: если вы пишите блок try-catch, это повод задуматься о том, не нужно ли что-то здесь выделить в новый метод.

Answer (score 0):

Исключения должны использоваться для обработки внештатного(исключительной) поведения, связанного с неожиданной ошибкой. Они не должны служить заменой проверкам выполнения условий. Если исключения можно избежать, просто проверив какое-то условие перед выполнением действия, то стоит так и сделать. Исключения следует приберечь для настоящих ошибок.
Например есть такой метод

```
public double getValueForPeriod(int periodNumber)
 {
   try
   {
      return values[periodNumber];
   }
   catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
   {
     return 0;
   }
}
```

Заменим выбрасывание исключения проверкой условия

```
public  double getValueForPeriod(int periodNumber)
{
   if (periodNumber >= values.length)
    {
      return 0;
    }
  return values[periodNumber];
}
```

Простой  условный оператор работает быстрее чем проверка исключения и иногда может быть очевиднее блока обработки исключения.Этот процесс называется рефакторинг кода.

***Порядок рефакторинга***

1. Создайте условный оператор для граничного случая и поместите его перед `try/catch` блоком
2. Переместите код из `catch`-секции внутрь этого условного оператора.
3. В `catch`-секции поставьте код выбрасывания обычного безымянного исключения и запустите все тесты.
4. Если никаких исключений не было выброшено во время тестов, избавьтесь от оператора `try/catch`.

В вашем примере можно `double.Parse("a")` заменить таким образом

```
 double result;
 string st="а";
 bool retVal= double.TryParse(st,result);
 if(retVal)
  {
     //ваш код
  }
```

Про обработке исключений можете читать [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/2.14.php)

Comment: @Андрей а вопрос в чем как можно сделать что бы в коде было меньше строк?или надо сыграть на быстродействие программы?как по мне втрое лучше